# Apache: Client-IP-based DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, documentroot

I don't know if this could be possible on apache yet, I've done hefty amount of research before coming here. but:

I have a VirtualHost running at **:80*, ServerName to somedomain.tld. What I want to achieve is if client 10.2.1.4 accesses somedomain.tld, the client will be served content from DocumentRoot /var/www/pages-1/. Then if 10.3.0.* accesses the same somedomain.tld, the client will get content from DocumentRoot /var/www/pages-2/. Is there any way to achieve this currently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a RewriteRule preceded by a RewriteCond that checks the remote_addr (remember using % for the vars, not $:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Servername somedomain.tld

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 10.2.1.4
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/pages-1/$1

  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 10.3.0.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/pages-2/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that this is the correct method (for me, at least).

Answer (score 3):

It won't be possible to change the document root, but you can rewrite the URL based on the client IP, something like...(not tested)...

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^10\.3\.0\.
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /pages-2/$1 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^10\.2\.1\.4$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /pages-1/$1 [P,L]
```

Although it might be simpler to use an [external rewriting program](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) if the number of IP addresses is very large.